# Hide an angular link in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have the below angular link which is in an aspx page

```
<a ng-if="SFpage.entryPointType == 0 &amp;&amp; SFpage.hideHeader == false" ng-click="moveToHold();" id="saveProgressBtn" class="btn btn-secondary ng-binding ng-scope">Save Progress</a>
```

How can I hide the above link in run time in browser? I have an option to insert code into this running aspx page but cannot access aspx page directly.

I tried using JS but it didn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("saveProgressBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your JS running at on the page?  Is it before the link is generated/displayed?  Try putting the script to change viability at the bottom of the page, then it should run after the link/page renders.

Comment: I can only add script or anything at the bottom of the page sing an insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-if="SFpage.entryPointType == 0 && SFpage.hideHeader == false"` you don't need to use `&amp;` in angularjs directives.

Comment: I cannot edit that link code but I can insert code into that page in the footer of the page.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, it might be a more simple option (compared to `getElementById`) -> `$("#saveProgressBtn).hide();`

Comment: Do you know if Jquery is referenced in the project?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364734/how-to-include-jquery-in-asp-net-project

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the browser's debug menu under the source tab, is it hitting that line of jQuery? (for debug purposes it might be easier to have a line like `var foo = $("#saveProgressBtn);` so you can inspect the object that the jQuery is returning, if anything).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190056/discussion-between-dortimer-and-krishnam).