# jquery-1.7.1.min.js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm building an asp.net web application.

I'm calling `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` using the  following code:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

I'm getting the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

This is the header of my aspx web form

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="***.aspx.cs" Inherits="***.***" MasterPageFile="~/Root2.Master" %>`

There is a script manager in the page

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>`

How to solve this?

Comment: Try changing the script reference to: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` without specifying the `http` protocol

Answer (score 0):

The jquery url that you are using have not "jquery-1.7.1.min.js"  file.

Use this url :
**https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js**

Comment: The question has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364734/how-to-include-jquery-in-asp-net-project

Comment: @abhav jquery 1.7.1 already exists no need to change the source.