# How can we include jQuery library in ASP.Net project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to find out how I can include Jquery in my ASP.Net project, is their anyone here to help me.

Comment: You can use `<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: Alternatively you can include it through Nuget

Answer (score 1):

You can include the script file directly in your page/master page, etc using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Us use a Content Delivery network like Google or Microsoft:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of including libraries is NuGet, it also makes it easier to manage if there are multiple people collaborating on the same project on GitHub or similar source control.

To add `jQuery` - right click your project in `Solution Explorer` and from the menu select `Manage NuGet Packages` then under `Browse` type jQuery in the search box and install it.

To include it in the HTML pages add a `script` tag:
[How to include jQuery in ASP.Net project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364734/how-to-include-jquery-in-asp-net-project)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio